# Jquery selector for parent input text

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have structure like this, generated via php code. Onclick on checkbox I want to fetch the value of input text just above it using jQuery.

```
                <input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-01" value="A" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="1">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="A" id="C-[Multi_1]-01">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-01"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr><div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-size:14px;">C-[Multi_1]-<b>02</b></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-02" value="AB" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="2">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="AB" id="C-[Multi_1]-02">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-02"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr><div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-size:14px;">C-[Multi_1]-<b>03</b></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-03" value="ABC" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="3">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="ABC" id="C-[Multi_1]-03">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-03"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr><div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-size:14px;">C-[Multi_1]-<b>04</b></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-04" value="" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="4">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="" id="C-[Multi_1]-04">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-04"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest and prev

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

https://api.jquery.com/prev/#prev-selector

```js
$('.checkbox_k').click(function () { 
  var test = $(this).closest('.form-check').prev('.form-group').find('.ans_text').val();
  console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-01" value="A" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="1">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="A" id="C-[Multi_1]-01">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-01"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr><div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-size:14px;">C-[Multi_1]-<b>02</b></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-02" value="AB" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="2">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="AB" id="C-[Multi_1]-02">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-02"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr><div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-size:14px;">C-[Multi_1]-<b>03</b></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-03" value="ABC" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="3">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="ABC" id="C-[Multi_1]-03">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-03"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr><div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-size:14px;">C-[Multi_1]-<b>04</b></label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control ans_text" name="C-[Multi_1]-04" value="" placeholder="..." onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" autocomplete="off" onchange="check_blank();" tabindex="4">
        </div><div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input checkbox_k" type="checkbox" value="" id="C-[Multi_1]-04">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="C-[Multi_1]-04"><small class="text-muted">Review Later</small></label>
</div>
<hr>
```